# How to create an Mp4 file from H264 raw data that I am receiving from a live streamer

Tags: mp4, h.264, live555

How to create an Mp4 file from H264 raw data that I am receiving from a live streamer (no predefined duration or moov atom), unfortunately can't use FFMPEG, I have to write my own code using live555. Can somebody help me with Mp4 container and how h264 data has to be pushed into it.? Thank you in advance : )

Answer (score 0):

There are several operations to be made to store H.264 raw data into MP4, among them:

- create box structures, in particular the `moov` box
- store the NAL units in a `mdat`box, possibly storing non-VCL NAL units in the `moov`box
- replace start codes with length fields

It also depends on your requirements. If you want to do the conversion on-the-fly, you have to use fragmented mp4. If you can store the H264 and then do the conversion, you may use non-fragmented mp4. In particular using [`MP4Box`](https://gpac.wp.mines-telecom.fr/mp4box/):

```
MP4Box -add file.264 file.mp4
```